# ServerConnection.Cancel method

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

The `SqlCommand` class has a [Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that, according to the documentation, allows one to cancel a command.

I'm looking for an equivalent method for commands executed through the [smo `Server` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx). The `ServerConnection` class (connectioncontext field of the server class) [has a Cancel method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.cancel.aspx) but the documentation is not clear on what it does.

Comment: I recommend avoiding SMO. It has a whole host of problems including not being even remotely thread safe. I ended up throwing it away and did everything with `sys.` views.

Comment: Maybe you want to disconnect the serverconnection? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.connectionmanager.disconnect

Comment: SQL Profiler doesn't seem to be clear about what it does either.  Whatever it does, doesn't show up in SQL Profiler as a logout event, or anything else I can discern.  I can cancel the connection and then continue what I was doing without throwing any errors.  I'm with Jonathan Allen.  Do it without SMOs.

Comment: Cancel is only useful when you have defined a `SqlBatch` for the command to be executed within.  This is generally done with the `SqlConnection` object but can be between the `SqlConnect` and `SqlCommand`, in the event you need to execute multiple Batches with each Batch containing multiple Commands within a single Connection timeline.

Answer (score 1):

The `SeverConnection.Cancel()` Method works **similarly** to the `SqlCommand.Cancel()` method and the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> If there is nothing to cancel, nothing occurs. However, if there is a command in process, and the attempt to cancel fails, no exception is
>   generated.
>
> In some, rare, cases, if you call ExecuteReader then call Close
>   (implicitily or explicitly) before calling Cancel, and then call
>   Cancel, the cancel command will not be sent to SQL Server and the
>   result set can continue to stream after you call Close. To avoid this,
>   make sure that you call Cancel before closing the reader or
>   connection.

Meaning that the cancel method will work, **If you call it before the call to the `close()` method.**

***If you call it after, the command will not be sent to the sql resulting in continues stream to the sql after to call the `close()` method.***

Moreover, if there is a command in process and the attempt to cancel fails, **you will not receive an error** as no exception is generated in such case.